# Are f4v-files the same as flv-files?

Tags: video, codec, flv

Are these two the same just with another extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Adobe's [F4V/FLV Technology Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/f4v.html) :

> As the de facto standard for dynamic
>   media on the web, Adobe Flash supports
>   a number of media formats. These
>   include two core open container
>   formats for delivering synchronized
>   audio and video streams: F4V and FLV.
>   F4V builds on the open standard
>   ISO/IEC 14496-12:2008 (MPEG-4 Part 12)
>   ISO base media file format and
>   supports H.264/AAC–based content. It
>   has a flexible structure and defines
>   specific supported codecs and
>   extensions, facilitating simplified
>   interoperability across tools,
>   services, and clients. FLV supports
>   codecs such as Sorensen Spark and On2
>   VP6, and encodes synchronized audio
>   and video streams in the same way as
>   they are encoded in SWF files.

So the two formats are distinct.

Another useful article is : [What is the difference between Flash Video (FLV), F4V and H.264](http://www.video-to-flash.com/f4v-h264-flv/).